# chef ruby warn output

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am getting all of a sudden this unusual warning. No idea what it means and what to do about it:

```
[2015-01-28T01:15:41-05:00] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for package[zlib1g-dev] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)
[2015-01-28T01:15:41-05:00] WARN: Previous apt_package[zlib1g-dev]: /root/chef-solo/cookbooks-2/rvm/providers/ruby.rb:174:in `block in install_ruby_dependencies'
[2015-01-28T01:15:41-05:00] WARN: Current  apt_package[zlib1g-dev]: /root/chef-solo/cookbooks-2/rvm/providers/ruby.rb:174:in `block in install_ruby_dependencies'
        * apt_package[zlib1g-dev] action install (up to date)
[2015-01-28T01:15:41-05:00] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for package[libssl-dev] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)
[2015-01-28T01:15:41-05:00] WARN: Previous apt_package[libssl-dev]: /root/chef-solo/cookbooks-2/rvm/providers/ruby.rb:174:in `block in install_ruby_dependencies'
[2015-01-28T01:15:41-05:00] WARN: Current  apt_package[libssl-dev]: /root/chef-solo/cookbooks-2/rvm/providers/ruby.rb:174:in `block in install_ruby_dependencies'
        * apt_package[libssl-dev] action install (up to date)
[2015-01-28T01:15:41-05:00] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for package[libyaml-dev] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)
[2015-01-28T01:15:41-05:00] WARN: Previous apt_package[libyaml-dev]: /root/chef-solo/cookbooks-2/rvm/providers/ruby.rb:174:in `block in install_ruby_dependencies'
[2015-01-28T01:15:41-05:00] WARN: Current  apt_package[libyaml-dev]: /root/chef-solo/cookbooks-2/rvm/providers/ruby.rb:174:in `block in install_ruby_dependencies'
        * apt_package[libyaml-dev] action install (up to date)
```

This never happened until I moved to ruby 2.2.0 locally. But this is happening on the server and I am not sure why. Any ideas?

Comment: Worth reading the ticket mentionned int the warn line: https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-3694 It means you have multiple recipes (at least two)  declaring the same package resource, so the chef-client clone it and show the warning

Comment: This is VERY normal, and not really concerning.  I'd say at least 50% of community cookbooks utilize cloned resources.  In fact, in a world of library cookbooks, it's almost impossible NOT to have them.